# Convert NSData to audio files in ios

Tags: ios, xcode, audio, converters, nsdata

Currently I'm calling webservice and get the datas from the webservices. I'm trying to make the audio file but it doesn't create any playable audio file. I can create it .caf file format but the audio is not playing.

```
NSString *dataPath = [[[Global sharedGlobals] documentsDirectoryPath] stringByAppendingPathComponent:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"/%@/recent.caf",_incidentID]];
[data writeToFile:dataPath atomically:YES];
```

Comment: Which player are you using to play that audio ?

Comment: [AVAudioPlayer](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVAudioPlayerClassReference/index.html)